# Does asking twice give bad performance?

Tags: php

I have a function:

```
function getMilk() {
    if($condition == true)
        return "Milk for you, madam";
    return false;
}
```

Example 1:

```
if(getMilk()) 
    echo getMilk();
```

Does the first example make PHP run for milk twice?

Example 2:

```
echo getMilk(); // don't check for milk first, just get it if they have it
```

If I was PHP I would rather get the second example. Then I wouldn't have to run to the store checking for milk, then running once more to get it.

Would example 2 be faster/better, or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Yes, the first approach will run the function twice, but the difference in performance will be neglligible in this case.

Comment: There is no such thing line too much milk for a madam =)

Comment: Why not echo getMilk all the time but return '' if false ?

Comment: Instead you assign to some variable and you check with the variable 
`$x = getMilk();`
`if($x) echo $x;`
in this case function is called only once.

Comment: try `if($milk = getMilk()) echo $milk;` this will call `getMilk()` only once

Comment: Ok, so there is a difference in performance, in this case only theoretical. But what if the function was `getEntireHeardOfCowsCheckingWhoHasMilk()`, then I should run it only once, right?

Comment: Performance isn't the only reason to avoid making the same function call twice. Some functions don't return the same result if you call them repeatedly. And there are also functions with side effects that you probably only want once.

Comment: `echo $condition ? 'Milk for you, madam' : ''`

Comment: Yes! PHP will call the function twice, because the condition could have changed since the last call; maybe not in this trivial example, but in most real world examples it can. PHP will do what you tell it to, and not start second guessing you. The way it should be.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, you are calling the function twice. Avoid doing that (because the function can be expensive to call) by doing one of the following:

```
$getMilk = getMilk();
if($getMilk) echo $getMilk;
```

You can reduce this to a one line (but unreadable) format:

```
if ($getMilk = getMilk()) echo $getMilk;
```

You can also use an inline `if` ternary, with a fallthrough:

```
echo getMilk()?:""; //Will echo the result of getMilk() if there is any or nothing.
```

Comment: The conditional assignment example is **far** from *unreadable*. This is very common in languages like PHP and Ruby, especially for such a simple assignment.

Comment: I agree it's not _unreadable_. However, I remember getting really confused once, before I understood it was  `=` and not `==`. That doesn't make it unreadable though.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice it gets unreadable if you do something like `if ($getMilk=getMilk() && $getMilk=="getMilk" /* maybe more assignments baked with comparisons here */)` anyone else who reads your code will not be able to see what's going on.

Comment: @apokryfos Well of course. In that case, you should obviously declare/evaluate conditions on multiple lines. But that wasn't the example given in the question or answer, so that wasn't what I was evaluating as *unreadable*. In the end, it's up to the judgment of whoever is doing the coding/review.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$milk` instead of `$getMilk`, or does PHP just have weird naming conventions?

Comment: @Bergi yes it would make more sense to name it `$milk` but as far as I know there's no PHP standard to impose rules that are as strict as that so I just went with something without really thinking about the convention much.

Comment: +1 for classifying it as unreadable. Avoid combining mutations (the assignment) with accesses (the `if` check). Keeping them separate always makes the logic easier to follow.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, PHP will call functions exactly as often as you tell it to. The function will be executed twice. You should not do that, since you don't intrinsically know how expensive any particular function is, and/or that may change in the future if you rewrite the implementation details of the function. Especially functions which have side effects (they modify something, e.g. they write to a file) must not be called more often than necessary.

Instead, store the function result in a variable:

```
$milk = getMilk();
if ($milk) {
    echo $milk;
}
```

This can even be inlined to:

```
if ($milk = getMilk()) {
    echo $milk;
}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't call every function mentioned. If you write ```false && getMilk()``` PHP will evaluate that as false without bothering to call getMilk()

Comment: I didn’t say “as often as mentioned”!

Answer (score 5):

The question is theoretical more than anything since the performance difference would be negligible.

That said, in your case, the second approach is fine since `false` does not translate to any sort of output. So

```
echo getMilk();
```

either echos the string, or nothing.

Comment: Actually I somewhat expected to see something in the output when you do `echo false;`, be it "false" or 0 or whatever.

Comment: Nope, in PHP echo'ing a falsy produces nothing.

Comment: @Utkanos not even a warning?

Comment: @OnklMaps False is not '0', its abscence of data; that being said, if you are afraid of echoing a 0 instead of False, you could just `return null` instead of `return false`

Comment: Ok. Just tried:
`echo NULL;
echo FALSE;
echo '';`
None of them displays any output, neither did they produce any PHP errors/warnings.

Comment: Correct. This differs from, say, JavaScript, which will cast a falsy value to a string representation of it, e.g. `alert("foo"+null+"bar")` > `foonullbar`.